# Illustrator Stroke Brush Definition Changes Color

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, shapes, stroke, brush

[image: https://gyazo.com/c4a72b275c78912eec7d4fa7f4d390ab]

As you see in the image, the shape and stroke are the same color, however when I apply Brush Definition to the stroke and it the colors looks lighter when technically they should be the same color. How can I fix that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illustrator stroke color appears lighter than same fill color](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20750/illustrator-stroke-color-appears-lighter-than-same-fill-color)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be available for every [type of brush](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/brushes.html#about_brushes), but try double-clicking that particular brush in the 'Brushes' panel and push the 'Paint Opacity' value to 100%.

[image]

If that doesn't work, you could do an 'Object → Expand Appearance', which turns brush strokes into actual objects, which you can then individually edit to 100% trasparency.

Further read: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/brushes.html#brush_options

Comment: https://gyazo.com/56ea27799deb884d41973381f6a7d5a9

This is the menu i get when I double click

Also Expand Appearance worked, thanks!

Comment: Yep, you get different options for different TYPES of brushes. My image shows the menu for a BRISTLE brush, and you're using an ART brush.